# How to correctly integrate <select> to change a table value?

Tags: angular

I'm having difficulty in integrating `<select>` tag in my table in where I would like to have an option to change a cell value by its corresponding id. Also I think there's something I need to correct on my API. I'm only new to Angular. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**my-table.component.html**:

```
<div class="box-body">
    <table id="my-table" *ngIf="myTable" datatable class="table table-borderless table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Doctype</th>
                <th>Sender</th>
                <th>Receiver</th>
                <th>Version</th>
                <th>Direction</th>
                <th>Count</th>
                <th>Created</th>
                <th>State</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let data of myTable">
                <td>{{ data.doctype_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.sender_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.receiver_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.doc_protocol_version }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.direction }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.count }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.created }}</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
                        <option *ngFor="let o of options" [ngValue]="data.id">{{ o.state }}</option>
                    </select>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="save()"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- / table -->
</div>
```

**my-table.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { MyTable } from './../my-table';
import { MyTableService } from './../my-table.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-table',
  templateUrl: './my-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-table.component.css'],
  providers: [MyTableService]
})

export class MyTableComponent implements OnInit {

    myTable: MyTable[];

    selectedOption: string;
    savedOption: string;

    options = [
        { state: "MSG_ERROR" },
        { state: "MSG_WAIT_FA" },
        { state: "MSG_WAIT_BATCH" },
        { state: "MSG_COMPLETE" }
    ]

    constructor(
            private myTableService: MyTableService,
            private location: Location,
            private router: Router
        ) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.myTableService.getMyTables()
        .subscribe(myTable => this.myTable = myTable);
    }

    save(): void {

        this.savedOption = this.selectedOption;
        this.myTableService.updateState() // How to pass the id and the selected option to be updated in the MySQL table
        .subscribe(() => this.goBack());
    }

    goBack(): void {

        this.location.back();
    }

}
```

**my-table.services.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { MyTable } from './b2b-status';

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class MyTableService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private myTableUrl = 'http://api/to/my/table';


  getMyTables (): Observable<MyTable[]> {

    return this.http.get<MyTable[]>(this.myTableUrl + '/error_state');
  }

  // Update State of my_table
  updateState(myTable: MyTable): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.put(this.myTableUrl + '/update/' + myTable.id, myTable, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

and my **PHP API**:

```
// Update state of my_table
$app->map(['GET', 'PUT'],'/my_table/update/{id}', function($req, $res, $args) {

    $err_msg = array('error' => 'Unable to update!');
    $succ_msg = array('success' => 'Updated successfully!');

    $id = $req->getAttribute('id');
    $state = $req->getParsedBody()['state'];

    $query = "UPDATE my_table
              SET state = '$state'
              WHERE id = '$id'";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(json_encode($err_msg));

    if($result) {
        return json_encode($succ_msg);
    }

    mysql_close($conn);
});
```

**UPDATE** I forgot to add the `MyTable` class:

```
export class MyTable {

    id: number;
    doctype_name: string;
    sender_name: string;
    receiver_name: string;
    doc_protocol_version: string;
    message_type: string;
    direction: string;
    state: string;
    current_state: string;
    created: string;
    updated: string;
    updated_by: string;
    count: number;
    error: string;
}
```

Comment: is there any default state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the corresponding data and options as parameters to your service.

To do that, you can get the related data object (or simply the data.id if you only need that) directly from your HTML because it is part of your *ngFor (ngFor="let data of myTable"). So it is the data your user is working on.

In your HTML :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="save(data)"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
```

In your Component :

```
save(data): void {
    let dataId: string = data.id;
    this.savedOption = this.selectedOption;
    // Pass the current data.id and the selected option to your service
    this.myTableService.updateState(this.myTable, dataId, this.savedOption) 
    .subscribe(() => this.goBack());
}
```

In your Service :

```
// Update State of my_table
  updateState(myTable: MyTable, dataId: string, savedOption: string): Observable<any> {
    // now you also have the selected dataId and savedOption
    // do whatever you like

    return this.http.put(this.myTableUrl + '/update/' + dataId, myTable, httpOptions);
  }
```

Update :

There are possible improvements (i.e no need of savedOption), but I tried to keep it the closest from your code so you can simply understand the general idea.

This service is used to make your API call to let your database know that a change is needed on myTable and what it is.
And because of what your API looks like and how it is already defined, it is also not necessary (and recommended) to send back the entire myTable by your service. It will be cleaner, faster and safer.

So what you only need in your case :

- the data.id: to identify the current working data by the user
- the new data state you want to change, in your case selectedOption

The rest is handle by your API, where you correctly get $id and $state (as you can see, only 2 variables, so your service should send only the same).

HTML :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="save(data.id)"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
```

Component :

```
save(dataId: string): void {
    let newState: string = this.selectedOption;
    this.myTableService.updateState(dataId, newState) 
    .subscribe(() => this.goBack());
}
```

Service :

```
updateState(dataId: string, newState: string): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.myTableUrl}/update/${dataId}`;
    return this.http.put(url, newState, httpOptions);
  }
```

API : Not very familiar with PHP but seems very correct to me

Hope it helps.

Comment: My bad, I thought you were the same person. Just reject my edit

Comment: It's working but I think, there's a problem with my API. It turns the state data to blank.

Answer (score 1):

**By keeping in mind that you want to apply different state option on different

records from the list**, below are the things will help you to save the selected option to the requested record.

Step 1) You should not create a single variable to handle the selected option for   all the records, because when you select an option, the same will be applicable to   all the records.
**Remove below variables, as not required**

```
selectedOption: string;
savedOption: string;
```

Step 2) Create the **state** variable in **MyTable** class.
This is required to hold the selected value from the drop-down.

Step 3) In HTML bind the state from the list to the selected option.

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of myTable">
   <td>{{ data.id }}</td>
   <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
   <td>{{ data.country }}</td>
   <td align="center">
     <select [(ngModel)]="data.state">
       <option disabled selected value="null">select</option>
       <option *ngFor="let o of options" [value]="o.state">{{ o.state }}</option>
     </select>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="save(data)">Save</button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Step 4) On click on save button, the control will go to the component class.

```
save(data) {
 // do your post-call here to save the current state
 // data contains the details
}
```

I have created the same example for you.
[View Demo Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sof-52985448)

Comment: sorry for asking this, but can you include the function for `save()` and `updateState()`?

Answer (score 0):

Html file

```
<div class="box-body">
        <table id="my-table" *ngIf="myTable" datatable class="table table-borderless table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Doctype</th>
                    <th>Sender</th>
                    <th>Receiver</th>
                    <th>Version</th>
                    <th>Direction</th>
                    <th>Count</th>
                    <th>Created</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let data of myTable">
                    <td>{{ data.doctype_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.sender_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.receiver_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.doc_protocol_version }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.direction }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.count }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.created }}</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <select [(ngModel)]="data.state"> <!-- change selectedOption to data.state and [ngValue]="data.id" to [ngValue]="o.state" so that both can match-->
                            <option *ngFor="let o of options" [ngValue]="o.state">{{ o.state }}</option>
                        </select>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="save(data)"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button> <!-- pass the row in save function -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

ts file

```
save(data): void {
    //data will contain the row which you wand to update
     this.savedOption = this.selectedOption;
     this.myTableService.updateState(data) // this is how to pass the id and the selected option to be updated in the MySQL table
     .subscribe(() => this.goBack());
}
```